# Different between Array.zeroCreate and Array.create in F#

Tags: arrays, f#

I am tring to create byte array and I used below line of code.

```
1. let mutable buffer = Array.zeroCreate<byte> //Showing type (int->byte[])
2. let buffer =Array.create<byte> 32768 0uy //showing type (byte[])
```

Please let me know which way is more suitable for specific situation and when what is different between this 2 line of code

Comment: In create you can specify the value, to be non-zero if you want

Comment: I have specified the value "0uy " in create.

Comment: So the end result is the same then

Comment: In first line of code, if i am trying assign byte array then is show error "The type '(int -> byte [])' does not support the 'equality' constraint because it is a function type"

Comment: `int->byte[]` is telling you it's a function. You forgot to pass in the size of the array. BTW this is not related to the question linked as duplicate. @JohnPalmer undo this please.

Comment: Also note that even though you want to mutate the individual entries in the array, you do not need to mark `buffer` as mutable.

Comment: I think it is a duplicate - I would post exactly the same answer.  I view the mistake in the mutable line as a typo given the title.

Comment: @JohnPalmer -I think that question and given answer both are different. I am asking about which statement used when more powerful way of coding.